# SVGs looking broken across sites (FB, LinkedIn, S.O etc)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, svg

So out of nowhere, I turned on my monitor and SVGs across sites in Google Chrome (up-to-date) look broken. Sometimes they're normal until hover, sometimes they're fine after a system restart. I can't think why. Is it possible the global npm package SVGO has anything to do with this? I was working on a project that I was mucking around with SVGO though I can't see that affecting browsers not linked to my local node modules.

Facebook menu:

[image: Facebook menu]

YouTube:

[image: YouTube]

StackOverflow:

[image: StackOverflow]

You get the idea.

(Have tested in Firefox and this is only happening in Chrome)

Again, just now, when I've powered off my display, and logged back in, this issue has away, though will magically appear again, only SVGs..

Anything come to mind why this is happening?